# Building a service locator (registry) for generic factories

Tags: java, generics, factory, service-locator

So I have a service locator to find factories (here registry):

```
public interface Registry {
  void addFactory(Factory<? extends Component> factory);
  Factory<? extends Component> getFactory(String name);
}
```

And a factory:

```
public interface Factory<C extends Component> {
  C createComponent();
  void render(C);
}
```

And use them this way:

```
Registry registry;
public <X extends Component> void createIt(String name) {
  Factory<X> factory = (Factory<X>)registry.getFactory(name); //<- I need to cast this
  X component = factory.createComponent();
  //..do something to component as it's a Component
  factory.render(component)
}
```

I haven't been able to find a way to capture that generic in the method. The information should be there to know that whatever the factory gives back (`X`) may be given back to the factory without having to know what it is. I've tried many different approaches without any success, I get a warning sooner or later.

**Edit:**

Here an example on how the factories look like:

```
public class SimpleFactory implements Factory<SimpleComponent> {
  public SimpleComponent createComponent() {
     return new SimpleComponent();
  }
  public render(SimpleComponent sc) {
    sc.doInThisSC();
  }
}
```

A Second factory might look like:

```
public class ComplexFactory implements Factory<ComplexComponent> {
  public ComplexComponentcreateComponent() {
     return new ComplexComponent();
  }
  public render(ComplexComponent cc) {
    cc.doInThisCC();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to express that `factory.render(factory.createComponent())` should always work, no matter what, so that I can do that with any factory retrieved from a registry.

Comment: `(Factory<X>)registry.getFactory(name);` will always give a unchecked warning

Comment: @Ramanlfc yes, the question is if I can change the signatures so that I don't need to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're only using methods that are defined on Component, you could do:

```
 Registry registry;
 public <X extends Report> void createIt(String name){
     Factory<Component> factory = registry.getFactory(name);
     Component component = factory.createComponent();
     // ...
     factory.render(component);
 }
```

The trick is that you have to work with the common denominator of all the different generics. When you have a generic like `F extends Foobar`, `F` is given to you as type `Foobar`, although you can recast it. Your `Registry` and `Factory` signatures define themselves as handling anything compatible with `Component`, but that means all they can assume they're getting is a `Component` and that's all you see without casting.

If you need extra methods that aren't defined as part of `Component` then you can create an interface that extends the `Component` interface (assuming `Component` is an interface):

```
public interface X extends Component{
    // Additional methods that will be required in addition to those
    // required by Component
}
```

You can then declare the generics as extending `X` and have all those methods available to you.

edit:

You could also have `Factory` be a parent class without a generic tag, then have the subtypes handle the polymorphism for you. Each subtype could then know by your program's logic that it was dealing with something that it created, and encapsulate the casting on their own for something that feels cleaner:

```
public class X implements Component{
    // ...
}

public class XFactory extends Factory{
    @Override
    public Component createComponent(){
        return new X();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Component in){
        // We know it's an X so we can cast it here:
        X real = (X)in;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, `factory.render` does not accept a `Component` it just accepts a `C` which is already defined as something that extends `Component`. This is indeed important since only the factory knows how to handle this type of Component. (Note I had a typo, Where it says Report it should have said Component)

Comment: `Component` extends `Component` by definition; I think I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do here. As long as you're not using anything specific to handle different types of `Component` differently then it's fine. If you are and you don't want to do casting, go for the wrapper interface suggestion. If you want to handle types of components programmatically, that's what casting is for. You could also do multiple signatures for each specific subclass you want to handle.

Comment: You could also have specific Factory subclasses that handle the polymorphism for you instead of using the generic syntax, then the factory could always know that it was getting back the type that it produced. That would probably still involve casting inside the factory, but it feels cleaner. When you start to get a little complicated like this you sometimes just have to do the casting; Java gives you it as a tool for a reason.

Comment: Indeed I could get rid of generics and implement one factory and use `instance of` to get the type and react accordingly, or even implement one factory per type. But the question here is if I can achieve this with generics, and most specifically, why not. With the generics approach it would be much more clear what is happening.

Comment: Well I don't think it's possible to do it only using generics because the Java compiler doesn't expose any way to track the origin of objects. Intuitively what you're saying makes sense, but CFG parsing is hard enough as is and so I'd expect each statement to be resolved independently, meaning that it can't make the connection that you're calling the method on the same factory that created the object. A more sophisticated type system like Haskell's might be able to support this but writing compilers is hard and I'm not sure there's enough of a need to justify the implementation.

Comment: It's also kind of weird to use generics in a factory pattern because the factory pattern is meant to abstract away the actual types that you're using and have you only think about the interface/parent type. Why use a factory pattern at all if you're going to be declaring the exact subtype anyway?

Comment: The point is that I won't be declaring the subtype at all. X is a generic. I'm just pinning it, whatever it is. The factory render methd is the weird thing, if anything, as that could indeed be implemented in the object itself (and should). This is just an example. It's just that I don't know why it's not working. The interface already defines that a factory can call render on an object it creates...

Comment: No, the interface defines that a factory must expose a `createComponent` method that returns a certain type, and a `render` method that hust happens to accept that same type. The distinction here is key. There is no link between the two methods, that's what I was saying; the Java compiler doesn't work that way. It also doesn't map objects created by a method to the original method/object that created them. Generics can't be used to "pin" types, as that's not possible in Java. Each line is executed with only the context defined by the data types used in that line.

Comment: You might want to play around with a syntax-tree generator (e.g. https://javaparser.github.io/javaparser/) so you can see how these statements are being broken down at compile time. If you think about it from the perspective of a language designer, simply ensuring type safety is incredibly complex and time consuming, so the level of context you're looking for here is generally beyond reach. Think about how you yourself would code a compiler that could handle this for programs on the scale of hundreds of thousands of lines of code.